# POST call through POSTMAN C#

Tags: c#, api, post, postman

I am trying to send a POST api call to my controller class in visual studio. Currently I have a class that will validate the input coming in,

```
  public class InReport
{
    public IEnumerable<IMatchingRule> Rules { get; set; }
}

public interface IMatchingRule
{
    int Page { get; set; }
}

public class RuleEquals : IMatchingRule
{
    public int Page { get; set; }
}

public class RuleRange : IMatchingRule
{
    public int Page { get; set; }
}

public class RuleGreaterThan : IMatchingRule
{
    public int Page { get; set; }
}

public class RuleLessThan : IMatchingRule
{
    public int Page { get; set; }
}
```

In POSTMAN I am trying to send the following:

```
 {
  "Rules" : 
  [
    "RuleGreaterThan"
    {
    "Page" : 10
      },
    "RuleLessThan" 
    {
    "Page" : 20
    }
  ]
}
```

But I keep getting an error response in POSTMAN as follows: 
 "Message": "Error converting value \"RuleGreaterThan\" to type 'Admin.Inbound.IMatchingRule'.

When I changed the ienumerable to pass in "RuleGreaterThan" class instead of the interface, it worked fine.

Question: 
What is the correct way to pass a POST call that takes an `ienumerable<INTERFACE>`?

Comment: I think you cannot post to an interface in the api method, it has to be concrete class.